# How to display the editing of one or more occurrence in a recurring event series in the outlook calendar?

Tags: .net, calendar, office365api, microsoft-graph-calendar, outlook-calendar

I am updating an existing outlook calendar viewing feature in our custom ASP.NET web application that works well and displays all the events except the recurring ones. Since I am new to Outlook Calendar APIs, I am aggressively learning how to implement and integrate the recurrence in our current system. I got to know that if an event is recurring it would have a Recurrence object and if it is not null it will hold the [Recurrence Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/recurrencepattern) and [Recurrence Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/recurrencerange) that will help me build the events to display in the calendar.

So, for an example, I have an event called **FooEvent** that's **repeating** itself daily for a year from 2 PM to 3 PM. from 19 August 2020 to 18 August 2021 as follows in the Outlook Calendar.
[image: FooEvent]

Through the *Outlook Calendar API*, while synching, I am receiving only one **Microsoft.Graph.OutlookItem** event object for **FooEvent** along with the property called **Recurrence**. Now, instead of creating every single event in the database based on this **Recurrence** rules (**Recurrence.RecurrencePattern** and **Recurrence.Range**), I am saving them in the SQL Server Database with this following schema so that the events can be built for a given period (i.e. 1 August 2020 to 31 August 2020) upon displaying.

[image: RecurringEventDatabaseSchema]

**So far no confusion until...**

The Outlook calendar gives the user these three options to update the recurring event.

- This event
- This and all following events
- All events in the series

[image]

If I edit an occurrence of the recurring event using any of the first two options to update the time. How would I keep track of that particular altered event in my current database as I only have the recurrence logic in my database? This gives rise to the need for another table that will have the rules exceptions, [something mentioned in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949552/how-to-create-recurring-calendar-events).

**One last piece of information**, that I am also making a delta request that will inform me if the whole event is deleted so the event in my database can be deleted (it's working fine). Also, I believe this delta request can also give me the data related to altering in the event but don't know how to implement that.

I am sure this must be a known problem but I couldn't find the legit solution online.

Also, here are some of the questions that look similar but are not.

- [editing an occurence in a recurrence event in outlook calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45815649/editing-an-occurence-in-a-recurrence-event-in-outlook-calendar)
- [Editing recurring events in Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46686866/editing-recurring-events-in-calendar)